# Make Qt's Debugger Aware of DLL Dependency in CMake (Windows)

Tags: windows, qt, cmake

In Windows, I have a CMake build under Qt that locates, via a find_library command, an A.lib file that is in a separate directory relative to its A.dll file. The A.lib file is then linked using a target_link_libraries command.

As far as the build goes, CMake has no problem not having the symbols in the .lib file defined until runtime.

At runtime, I use windeployqt to successfully assemble all dependent libraries (indluding the A.dll file) into a separate deploy directory from the build directory, and I'm able to run there just fine.

However, to run via Qt's debugger, Qt runs the executable from the build folder rather than the deploy folder. By default, Qt attempts to add the build library folders to the PATH variable as well. Admirably, it also attempts to scan dependencies such as the Qt libraries and the path to A.lib and adds them to the PATH as well. Unfortunately, it does not add the path to A.dll, resulting in a failed DLL dependency error in the launched thread.

I can easily get around this by adding the path to A.dll to the PATH in Qt's run section of the Project tab. However, I'm curious, is it possible to make Qt catch this dependency via some CMake command and automatically add A.dll to the PATH, similar to how it caught other dependencies correctly? I'm not sure how Qt attempts to find dependencies, but in a previous QMake iteration of the build, the path to A.dll was appended automatically.

Comment: `find_library`  doesn't link. Loading dynamic libraries is not the role of CMake but the linker. You are mixing up a lot of things in your question. If you wish to know how `.dll` searches work in Windows, I advise you to check the MSDN docs.

Comment: @MilanŠ. right, find_library does the library finding, while something like target_link_libraries does the linking (and can take the output of a find_library command as an input). My question is about a runtime feature that Qt has to append build library search paths to PATH (Windows) or LD_LIBRARY_PATH (Linux). This link about a bug related to this feature might help give some background: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-26110

Comment: The bug is from 2021 and is fixed if this prepending to PATH is a feature of QT then I have to ask - are you running the latest version? There is no way for CMake to change environment variables permanently, you can set Environment variables during the CMake generation process but those are only temporary (for a good reason) - it works by creating a new "sub" shell in which these variables are changed. I do not know of anything that could permanently change variables (in CMake). CMake has nothing to do with what happens after you build/install it. It's just a build automation tool.

Comment: @MilanŠ. that's a great question. My version seems to be older than the one mentioned in the bug, but on closer examination, the other build library paths, and also the A.lib path, are successfully being prepended to the PATH variable. My guess would be that the bug was patched in older versions, but I haven't confirmed that beyond verifying behavior.

Comment: I found the CMake-generated json file that Qt uses to search for these dependencies, and the A.lib one was in .cmake\api\v1\reply\target-projectName-debug in the {artifacts {link {commandFragments} } } section. It seems my question can be reduced to: is there a way to add the A.dll file to that json section via CMake? It sounds like the answer is no based on what you mentioned earlier, but I find it helpful to make the question more specific. It's unfortunate that MSVC compilers use a separate .lib and .dll file for one library, as this approach would work perfectly if they were unified.

Comment: To your point, you're right in saying that CMake doesn't change the environment variables permanently. The approach Qt takes, if this particular feature is enabled, is: parse the .cmake\api\v1\reply\target-appname JSON file for library dependencies -> create a sub shell with a PATH (on Windows) or LD_LIBRARY_PATH (Linux) environment variable that includes these dependencies prepended ->run the selected application from this shell

Comment: This created json file sounds more like a QT creation rather than CMake. I would have to look into this. CMake IIRC doesn't create any `.json` files natively. I might be wrong here, but I have been using it for a very long time and this is the first time I hear of this. QT probably appends some of their own `.cmake` scripts that generate it. If that's the case then modifying them would be an option.

Comment: Ofcourse there are 2 files that might be what you mean i.e. `CMakePresets.json` and `CMakeUserPresets.json` but those are config files that are user created - not generated.

Comment: [here is a link to cmake-presets doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) But I dont think its what you are looking for

Comment: @MilanŠ. Thanks, I'm always happy to learn more here. That said, I think this is not the presets file that MSVC (and perhaps other CMake IDE's) use, but one that is generated as part of CMake's file api, which I recently learned about: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-file-api.7.html. That said, this issue apparently has been known to Qt as those links in my answer show, I'm glad this has been fixed already!

Comment: Ah nice, learnt something new as well

Answer (score 0):

As of Qt 7.0.1, Qt added a workaround that allows the user to add dll paths to CMake via a target_link_directories command and have those parsed by Qt from the Cmake file-api to add to the PATH variable in Windows.

This fix is in Qt Creator 7.0.1, see the change summary here:

https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt-creator/qt-creator/+/404290

And the issue prompting this change on the official Qt website (which is where I should've looked first):

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-27201?workflowName=Qt+Bug+Tracking+v2.4&stepId=8

It should be noted that a workaround for this issue was added to Qt Creator at an earlier point (I'm not sure exactly when) that looked one directory above the \lib folder for a \bin folder (see the code that implements this workaround, and performs the CMake file-api queries in general [here](https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator/blob/0be9639e6f4f7c9713b8fee32281225ab72e22fb/src/plugins/cmakeprojectmanager/fileapidataextractor.cpp#L296)).

The latter workaround happened to not work for my particular MSVC-built library folders, since there the lib and bin folders are themselves in folders with architecture and OS information, with a common parent three and two folders above, respectively.

Updating Qt Creator to 7.0.1 and using the target_link_directories command solves this issue.